# session value in jquery & static web method

Tags: jquery, session

I tried to get session value like this

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["type"]=mast.type;
```

and try to accessing value like this

```
var username = '<%= Session["type"] %>';
            alert(username);
```

but this shows null

where as i got value in mast.type

Comment: why not use localStorage, what is this session plugin that you are using?

Comment: how i use this???? i use jquery .session

Comment: there's a thing called documentation, you should try reading it sometimes

Comment: @madalinivascu check update

Comment: in this instance use cookie, there are available both front and back end

Comment: if i use session how i do this

Comment: simple: first :you read the documentation, second: you see some simple examples,3th :you do it yourself